# No context type found in the assembly after upgrading to ef6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

My project was working fine but now having problem after upgrading entity framework 5.0.0 to 6.1.0 using packet manager console.
update-database doesn't work in Project.Data:

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly

any suggestion? thank you.

Comment: Can you describe your project structure?

Comment: Were you using migrations previously? If so, then perhaps you can make a backup of your existing Configuration.cs, remove it from the project and run the enable-migrations command.

Comment: I use Repository pattern and my Context is in Data Layer.I were using migrations previously on ef5 without any problem. running enable-migrations command again did not help me.